# Slow speed and bad connection on Ubuntu 16.04 lts with Realtek 8188ee

Tags: network-manager, internet, realtek

I have an issue. I have a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, ​​and always had problems to connect with the WiFi. I use it in a HP Pavilion 15 laptop, the WiFi adapter is Realtek 8188ee, and the kernel version is 4.4.0-143. I have solved it temporarily using a driver made by a third party *rtlwifi_new*. It allows me to connect and maintain the connection, however this is still very slow. It is 65 Mb/s and in Windows works normally with 100 Mb/s. Is there a compatibility problem? How can I improve my connection speed?

wifi-information
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/pymQNGVHxv/

Comment: You mean Megabit per seconds or MegaBytes per seconds in your examples?

Comment: hi mature, mb means megabit.